# Authentication Error After Lock

Tags: release-juno, security

So a little issue here. Whenever I unlock the system after it locks (either manual or automatic lock), the system does not seem to fully unlock. As in, I have to authenticate every single system action. Mounting drives, updating repositories in appcenter, etc, all need another entry of my password.

Anyone know what is going on?

About my system: ASRock B450M PRO4; Quad-Core AMD Ryzen 5 2400G with Radeon Vega Graphics; elementary OS 5.0 Juno

Comment: Please do not ask about multiple problem in a same question instead create separate question. If you still have the problem with shutdown button please create another question explain the issue. Please read, [How do I ask a good question?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ok, will do. 
I thought to group them together because it seemed to me a problem with the keyring or authentication not allowing full user access to even regular tasks. Things which regularly did not need passwords on initial boot, now required them after a lock screen login. (And I don't do things via terminal; only via the apps loaded in EOs)

Answer (score 0):

> As in, I have to authenticate every single system action. Mounting
>   drives, updating repositories in appcenter, etc, all need another
>   entry of my password

That is normal or seems to me. Let's say you want to update the repositories, you opened up Terminal([terminal](/questions/tagged/terminal)) then executed `sudo apt update` and its for your password! Why? Because you used `sudo` which is gives you super user privilege(root). And if you perform another `sudo` task right after it usually won't ask for password. The whole 'security' in Linux distributions have been taken seriously so, this is okay and this is how it's good.

If you want to login as root and do stuff, execute `sudo su`.

Comment: What I mean to say is that things that normally do not need an additional password on initial power-on, now does after a lock screen login.
Example: I am updating via Appcentre, it asks for password when I open the app; then password for each and every upgrade; then password to update the repositories after the upgrade
Example: mount drives via file manager requires password (only after lock screen login; no password needed on initial poweron)

Comment: I think I understand, please read the above text which explains why it asks for password.

Comment: I understand why it asks for a password. But this is unusual behaviour. Previous versions never has this issue (been with EOs for 6yrs).
And it does not explain why it only asks for passwords after a lock-screen, while not on initial boot (I have auto-login at boot enabled).
Ex: After bootup, I can go to file manager and mount a drive then unmount without a password prompt. But if I lock the computer (SUPER+L) then log back in, it will ask for a password to mount the drive (or to use appcentre; or even to poweroff).
Why the discrepancy between initial login, and login after lock screen?